# How can I filter in django so I can sort each object into its correct parent?

Tags: python, django, sorting, filter

I am building a location specific app. What I would like to do is display a list of schools by city and state. The pages are organized by state. In turn, the state pages display schools that are sorted by city.

State 
--- City
------ School
--- City
------ School

I can get the state page to display the list of cities just fine. But rather than sorting out cities from different states, I get a list of all the cities without them being sorted into their correct states. I also can't get the list of schools to filter into the correct city. The cities and schools appear in every state - even the incorrect ones.

models.py

```
class SchoolList(models.Model):
    school_list_image = models.ForeignKey(Photo, default='')
    school_list_state = models.ForeignKey('place.state', default='')
    school_list_city = models.ForeignKey('place.city', default='')
    school_list_zip_code = models.ForeignKey('place.zip', default='')
    school_list_address = models.ForeignKey('place.address', default='')
    school_list_contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    school_list_university = models.ForeignKey('place.university', default='')
    school_list_professionalschool = models.ForeignKey('place.professionalschool', default='')
    school_list_summary = models.ForeignKey(Summary, default='')    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_list_university.university_name

class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    state_abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-state_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_name

class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-city_name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cities'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name

class Zip(models.Model):
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-zipcode']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.zipcode

class University(models.Model):
    university_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')
    university_summary = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    university_image = models.ForeignKey(Photo, default='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Universities'
        ordering = ['-university_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.university_name

class ProfessionalSchool(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Professional Schools'
        ordering = ['-school_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name

class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    address3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Addresses'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

views.py

```
class StateDetail(ListView):
    model = StateSchoolListArticle
    template = 'state_detail.html'

    context_object_name = 'article_state_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StateDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['school_list'] = SchoolList.objects.all().order_by('school_list_city')
        return context
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', StateDetail.as_view(), name='state_detail'),
```

template.html

```
{% for school in school_list %}
<h2>{{ school.school_list_city.city_name }}</h2>
<div class="school_image">
    {% cloudinary school.school_list_image.image format="jpg" crop="fill" %}
</div>
<div class="demo_wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-4 columns">
            <div class="school_data_wrapper">
                <h3>{{ school.school_list_university.university_name }}</h3>
                <h4 style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                    {{ school.school_list_professionalschool.school_name }}      </h4>
                <h4>{{ school.school_list_address.address }}</h4>
                <h4>{{ school.school_list_city.city_name }}, {{ school.school_list_state.state_name }} {{ school.school_list_zipcode.zipcode }}</h4>                                                
                <h4><a href="tel:555555555">{{ school.school_list_contact.telephone }}</a>
               </h4>
                <h4><a href="" rel="external nofollow">
                    {{ school.school_list_contact.website }}</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-8 columns">
            <h3>Summary</h3>
            <p style="padding: 20px 0;">{{ school.school_list_summary.summary }}<a href="link to university detail page">...more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont understand your model structure. Can you post also your other models please? Also I dont think you want to have `default=''` in any `ForeignKey` field - just set `null=True` there instead.

Comment: Posting them now. Thanks for the heads up on the ForeignKey

Comment: Have you tried exploring the `regroup` template tag? Seems like it may solve what you need. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: What is the purpose of `SchoolList`? I'd expect a data model like `School`, `City`, `State`. What are the `place.*` names you are referencing to? What is `StateSchoolListArticle`. And what advantage do you get from adding the class name as a prefix to every field?

Comment: I created SchoolList because it was the only way I could think of grouping things together so that the schools could group into the cities and cities into states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really an answer, but it was too long to put it in the comment.

I dont like the `SchoolList` model at all. It is violating [Normal Forms](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php), and it will bite you sooner or later. The models should represent the real world. So when you have a zip code, it doesnt exist just like that. It is related to a city. And when you have city, it is related to a state. So the models should look like this:

```
class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    state_abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='')

class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)

class Zip(models.Model):
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

class Address(models.Model):
    zip = models.ForeignKey(Zip)
    ...
```

Now, when you have address, you want to have a `ForeignKey(Zip)` there. This way you will have transitively defined `Zip`, `City` and `State` in there, so you can (or more like *should*) remove them from the `SchoolList` model.
Then when you want to filter the schools by state, you can do it this way:

```
SchoolList.objects.filter(address__zip__city__state=state_object)
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought that would be right way to do it. But I couldn't figure out to make it work. I'm still getting the hang of this. Much thanks  again.